# How can i make a Bump/setoff accurate to its own texture map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

I'been trying to make a kind of replica of the planet Ceres, but it lacks the 'bump', the bad thing is, the image takes all the object, so the parts that i need with bump (the holes, for example) appear, alongside everything else, and the texture itself doesn't work well at all.

**As you can see on the picture, i have a reference, but i want to get that kind of displacement/bump.**

[image]

**In other hand, as i said, if i add the same image as bump, the result get worse..**
[image]

**Is there any solution for this? what do i need in my Nodes?**

Comment: I think this question is similar to this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32155/how-can-i-modify-a-displacement-texture-roughness Check out my answer there.

Comment: I'd say you have too much displacement. Try scaling it back, either with a bump node or a math node if you want to use the displacement output.

Comment: Hmm, the displacement doesn't show any option to change it, where i can change those parameters?

Comment: Math node set to multiply. You may want to use a color ramp as well